# Mongoose multi connections same DB with Hapijs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, hapi.js

I'm working with `Hapijs` and `mongoose`, The problem is that some `URL` are really intensive with `mongoose`.
`A, B, C` are 3 different schemas. This query can take some time, depending on the `array` size. The problem is when `mongoose` is processing this request, it can't process another one. For example, if some is doing an Import, no one else can login or what so ever to the system.

I tried the option of mongoose `poolSize`, but that does not work.

Any `ideas` on how can I overcome this?

```
  buildArticle: function(articles, req, res) {
    let bulkUpdateOps = articles.map(function(article) {
      return A.findOneAndUpdate(
            query
        )
        .then(function() {
          return B.findOneAndUpdate(
            query
          );
        })
        .then(function(resultado) {
            some stuff
        })
        .then(function(resultado) {
          return {
            updateOne: {
              filter: {
               query
              },
              update: {
                data
              },
              upsert: true
            }
          };
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          return res(Boom.badImplementation("Error: ", err));
        });
    });

    Promise.all(bulkUpdateOps)
      .then(function(ops) {
        return C.bulkWrite(ops, {
          ordered: true,
          w: 1
        });
      })
      .then(_ => {
        return res("Imported");
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return res(Boom.badImplementation("Error: ", err));
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with Indexes and .lean(). One of the query was a find with multiples fields and text based. I made some index and the speed improved a lot (plus the use of .lean() ).